# Unable to install And udate android platform-tools and tool for api build display showing checksum error..?

Tags: android, ionic-framework

Please see the below image, Before installation showing checksum issue. Please any budy noise resolve this type of issue.

[image]

Comment: Submit same error on android studio support team as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this

> go to tools ---> Options ---> Clear Cache. Then Packages ---> Reload

Comment: This should be comment.